# PublishSubject blockingLast() hangs Android app and not invoke

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a problem with getting the last emitted value from the Subject

This is my class which is responsible for emitting and observing the battery changes:

```
class BatteryLevelProvider @Inject constructor(
app: App
) {

private val context: Context = app
private val receiver: PowerConnectionReceiver = PowerConnectionReceiver()

init {
initializeReceiver()
}

private fun initializeReceiver() {
IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).let { intentFilter ->
  context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
  }
}

companion object {
 val batteryLevelSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
}

fun observeBatteryLevel(): Observable<Int> = batteryLevelSubject.distinctUntilChanged()

fun getCurrentBatteryLevel(): Int {
Timber.d("getCurrentBatteryLevel: ENTERED")
val blockingLast = batteryLevelSubject.blockingLast(0)
Timber.d("getCurrentBatteryLevel: $blockingLast")
return blockingLast
}

inner class PowerConnectionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
  val level: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
  val scale: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
  val percentage= (level / scale.toFloat() * 100).toInt()
  batteryLevelSubject.onNext(percentage)
  Timber.d("Battery changed: $percentage")
    }
  }

}
```

When i invoke the 
    getCurrentBatteryLevel()
It reach the blockingLast never get return the value and hangs the app.
What is the reason and how to handle this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subject.blockingLast(0)` means the following: get the last value after the stream has completed emitting values and if it has completed without emitting anything then return the default value.

That means that `blockingLast` will wait until it receives `onComplete` event because only then it can figure out that the stream has ended (and emit last value). `PublishSubject` creates an **infinite stream** and you never call `batteryLevelSubject.onComplete` to end the stream manually and that's why it hangs forever.

You can easily fix that by changing `PublishSubject` to `BehaviorSubject`. The main difference between them is that `BehaviorSubject` caches the last received value which can then be received by anyone. Also, you need to change `batteryLevelSubject.blockingLast(0)` to `batteryLevelSubject.value` to get the last cached value (and it won't block anything!). But be aware that the value may be null at the first run when you haven't put there anything yet. You can easily fix that by creating `BehaviorSubject` with default value like so:

```
val subject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)
```

Comment: thanks, but it still did not resolve my issue - batteryLevelSubject.value still blocks the app

Comment: That's strange because it shouldn't. If you look in the source code of the getValue method you will see that all it does is get the value from the AtomicReference and checks whether it is indeed a value or some other event.

Comment: Weird, i just have to remove my app, maybe something was cached. Anyway  thanks, i accept your answer